# Printing to a .txt file from two separate dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm attempting to print a list of grades to a saved txt file. The problem is, I have two separate dictionaries, one for grades and one for marks. They share a common key of student ID so I've tried using a nested loop and a If call, but it simply returns the last value on the list over and over again.

Code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
marks=False
while marks is False:
    try:
        stuff=input("which file do you want to open? ")
        f=open(stuff)
        lines=f.readlines()
        f.close()
        marks=True
    except:
        print("No good, try again")
a={}
count=0
for line in lines:
    value=line.split(',')
    ID=value[0]
    mark=value[1]
    print(ID, mark)
    a.update({ID:mark})
    count+=1
print()
print("Number of students is: ",count)
grades={}
for k,v in a.items():
    v=int(v)
    if v in range(0,35):
        grade="E"
        print("Student with id number ",k,"scored mark",v,"and a grade of",grade)
        grades.update({k:grade})
    elif v in range(35,50):
        grade="D"
        print("Student with id number ",k,"scored mark",v,"and a grade of",grade)
        grades.update({k:grade})
    elif v in range(50,65):
        grade="C"
        print("Student with id number ",k,"scored mark",v,"and a grade of",grade)
        grades.update({k:grade})
    elif v in range(65,80):
        grade="B"
        print("Student with id number ",k,"scored mark",v,"and a grade of",grade)
        grades.update({k:grade})
    elif v in range(80,101):
        grade="A"
        print("Student with id number ",k,"scored mark",v,"and a grade of",grade)
        grades.update({k:grade})
print(a)
print()
print(grades)
print()
for k,v in a.items():
    v=int(v)
    if v in range(0,35):
        bar='#'*int(v/2)
        print(k,v,bar)
    elif v in range(35,50):
        bar='#'*int(v/2)
        print(k,v,bar)
    elif v in range(50,65):
        bar='#'*int(v/2)
        print(k,v,bar)
    elif v in range(65,80):
        bar='#'*int(v/2)
        print(k,v,bar)
    elif v in range(80,101):
        bar='#'*int(v/2)
        print(k,v,bar)
print()
f=open("report.txt",'w')
print('{a:^12}{b:^8}{c:^8}'.format(a='student ID', b='Mark', c='Grade'),file=f)
for k,v in a.items():
    k=ID
    v=mark
    for g,h in grades.items():
        h=grade
        if g==ID:
            print('{a:^12}{b:^8}{c:^8}'.format(a=ID,b=mark,c=grade),file=f)
f.close()
```

Comment: You may want to add a language tag, so people will find your question easier.

Comment: @GrandMcKinnon - This is python. Is it 2 or 3? Also, can you share a bit about your two files? It could be junk records but it is easier for someone to test their answer and help you. Thank you.

Comment: When asking a code related question, it's always necessary to add a tag for the language you're using. It helps get the question in front of the people who may be able to answer it more quickly, and it also helps future readers here who are searching to find a solution find it more easily. Please [edit] your post to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last loop, the code iterates over key/value pairs of the dictionary, but never really uses them, as it instead overwrites them.

Let me show you with some comments:

```
for k,v in a.items():
    # here, k and v are picked from the dictionary 'a'
    k=ID    # <-- this always overwrites the value of k to ID
    v=mark  # <-- this always overwrites the value of v to mark

    for g,h in grades.items():  # since dictionaries 'a' and 'grades' have same 
                                # key, you don't need to iterate through all the keys
        h=grade
        if g==ID:
            print('{a:^12}{b:^8}{c:^8}'.format(a=ID,b=mark,c=grade),file=f)
```

A better way to proceed is as follows:

```
f=open("report.txt",'w')
print('{a:^12}{b:^8}{c:^8}'.format(a='student ID', b='Mark', c='Grade'),file=f)

for ID,mark in a.items():   # iterate over key/value pairs of 'a'
    grade = grades.get(ID)  # just lookup the value from ID
    print('{a:^12}{b:^8}{c:^8}'.format(a=ID,b=mark,c=grade),file=f)

f.close()
```

I would also change the variable name from 'a' to something more descriptive.

Comment: awesome thanks!, i ended up combining the dictionaries and then pulling key and both values from that but your way def was easier!

Answer (score 0):

combining both dictionaries then pulling all the variables from the new dictionary:

```
ds = [a, grades]
d = {}
for k in grades.keys():
  d[k] = tuple(d[k] for d in ds)
print()

for k,[g,m] in d.items():
    print('{a:^12}{b:^8}{c:^8}'.format(a=k,b=m,c=g),file=f)
```